# Detecting statistically significant events/changes in time series

Tags: events, time-series

My dataset consists of daily stats where the numbers are similar to each other but events occur on certain days which causes the next set of days to plateau around a new average.

I'm wondering whats the best way to automatically detect these events in historical data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for a "level shift". See Tsay's work on this,  www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf

We have spent a lot of our work in this area!